# Add tags to input field with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, tags

I'm using a plugin for Wordpress called WP User Frontend. Basically it allows users to post from the front-end of the website.

There is a feature which allows users to add tags themselves, however, this is just a normal input text field, and I don't want them to create countless of new tags.

**So basically what I want is for them to be able to click on several buttons which will add the tags to the input field, while also disabling their manual input.**

Comment: are you able to modify both the html and javascript?

Comment: Yes I have full access to edit whatever I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a script that converts the checkbox input into whatever format (say, a string of words separated by spaces) was needed for the original tags input. Here is an example script that would both insert the checkboxes to the page underneath the original input and put the resulting values into the original field, ensuring it gets posted the same way. (You could then hide the original field if you don't want it displayed.) http://jsfiddle.net/zLVTp/8/

```
var tags = ['cows', 'sheep', 'dogs'],
    inp, label, ch = document.createElement('fieldset'),
    f = document.getElementById('tagField'); 
        // ^ The original input has id=tagField
f.readOnly = true;
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    inp = document.createElement('input');
    label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = tags[i];
    label.htmlFor = 'tag_' + tags[i];
    inp.type = "checkbox";
    inp.name = "tagSet";
    inp.className = 'tagCBs';
    inp.value = tags[i];
    inp.id = 'tag_' + tags[i];
    ch.appendChild(inp);
    ch.appendChild(label);
    inp.onchange = (function() {
        var th = inp;
        return function() {
            var sp, r = [];
            if (th.checked && f.value.indexOf(th.value) == -1) {
                if (f.value == '') f.value = th.value;
                else f.value += ' ' + th.value;
            }
            else if (!th.checked) {
                sp = f.value.split(' ');
                for (var j = 0; j < sp.length; j++) {
                    if (sp[j] != th.value) r.push(sp[j]);
                }
                f.value = r.join(' ');
            }
        }
    })();
}
f.parentNode.appendChild(ch);​
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using the code on my website but the form doesn't seem to pick up the values in the input box. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean - can you try and describe a bit more precisely what behaviour you want and what happens instead?

Comment: When I press the checkboxes the text shows up in the input field as requested. However, the text in the input field (cows sheep dogs) doesn't seem to be posted by the form. It's like the input field "tagField" is completely empty even though the text shows up in there.

Comment: My mistake, `f.disabled = 'disabled'` should be replaced with `f.readOnly = true`. (I've fixed this in the code above.) Turns out that disabling the field stops it from posting any information. Alternatively, you could hide the field (`f.style.display = 'none'`)

Answer (score 0):

html checkbox seems to fit your need, no ? you have to modify the form and replace the text-area with checkbox (dirty but simple)